# arduino didn't working properly

Tags: arduino-nano

[image] arduino didn't working properly. When i using a alarm program on pin 6 and a blinking led on pin 2 alarm sound beeps once and then goes down but when using only alarm program it works perfectly. I see that arduino can handle one pin perfectly but when it comes to use two pins together it can't handle properly

```
float sinVal; 
int toneVal; 
void setup(){ 
                pinMode(7, OUTPUT); 
                pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
} 
void loop(){ 
                for(int x=0; x<180; x++)
                                { //convert angle of sinusoidal to radian measure 
                                sinVal = (sin(x*(3.1412/180))); 
                                //generate sound of different frequencies by sinusoidal value 
                                toneVal = 2000+(int(sinVal*1000)); 
                                //Set a frequency for Pin-out 8 
                                tone(7, toneVal); 
                                delay(2); }
                digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
                delay(100);
                digitalWrite(2, LOW);
                delay(200);
}
```

Comment: please format your code properly .... highlight the code and click on the `{}` icon

Comment: How did you manage to get a tone playing with such a big speaker? I thought hooking up such a low impedance load would fry the pin it's connected to.

Comment: You need to learn the basics of electroncis before you start hooking random things up like that. That circuit is completely incorrect and most likely will damage the Arduino. Start by reading tutorials, and don't randomly miss out components just cus you don't fancy using them.

Answer (score 0):

with this wiring setting pin 2 HIGH shorts pin 2 to ground and Arduino dies. you must use a resistor in series with LED. and better use one with the speaker too.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure but its your power supply. I suggest to used another power supply on your arduino. Use 9V battery and connect it to Vin(+) and GND(-) and test if there is an improvement.

Comment: to burn pin 2 for sure?

Comment: No. I’m sure you are using Arduino Nano. Vin is on pin 30. And the official website state the Arduino deals 7-12v. Input Voltage (recommended): 7-12 V
Input Voltage (limits): 6-20 V

Comment: the LED on the photo shorts pin 2 to ground